# React Native Search Bar. Don't know how to fix it

Tags: react-native

I am making a search bar for my app. I am stuck at the moment, please help me find my error.

I hope you can help me out, thank you.

When I go onto expo on my phone the search bar is compact together and I am not able to click on it or interact with it in any way.

I am new to react-native and don't know how to move on.

This app has different screens and this screen is for handling my search queries.

Im sure its just a stupid mistake

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import MenuImage from '../../components/MenuImage/MenuImage';


export default class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    return {
      headerRight: (
        <MenuImage
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.openDrawer();
          }}
        />
      ),
      headerTitle: (
        <SearchBar
          containerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
            borderTopColor: 'transparent',
            flex: 1
          }}
          inputContainerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#EDEDED'
          }}
          inputStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#EDEDED',
            borderRadius: 10,
            color: 'black'
          }}
          searchIcond
          clearIcon
          //lightTheme
          round
          onChangeText={text => params.handleSearch(text)}
          //onClear={() => params.handleSearch('')}
          placeholder="Search"
          value={params.data}
        />
      )
    };
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.setParams({
      handleSearch: this.handleSearch,
      data: this.getValue
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the content of the topbar is static, try to insert the search bar in the top of the main view of the page and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lahkim! I really am new to this, could you maybe explain or show me what you mean?